# Сортировка по выделенному столбцу таблицы

Tags: javascript

Необходимо реализовать выбор столбца по щелчку на название столбца(чтобы столбец остался подсвеченным) и сортировку всей таблицы по данному столбцу - по убыванию и по возрастанию. Необходимо сделать без плагинов.

Имеется вот такая HTML разметка и JS файл:

```js
var arr = [
{
 id:'1',
 name:'Вася',
 date:'15.06.2018',
 count:'11'
},
{
 id:'2',
 name:'Петя',
 date:'23.1.2018',
 count:'23'
},
{
 id:'3',
 name:'Иван',
 date:'12.03.2017',
 count:'3'
},
{
 id:'4',
 name:'Александр',
 date:'20.12.2010',
 count:'1'
},
{
 id:'5',
 name:'Евгений',
 date:'12.09.2018',
 count:'112'
},
{
 id:'6',
 name:'Мария',
 date:'1.08.2016',
 count:'122'
},
{
 id:'7',
 name:'Анастасия',
 date:'20.11.2018',
 count:'34'
},
{
 id:'8',
 name:'Степан',
 date:'12.1.2019',
 count:'10'
},
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.openModule').click(function(){
        $('.module').show();
        $('.openModule').hide();
    });
    $('.closeModule').click(function(){
        $('.module').hide();
        $('.openModule').show();
    });
    $('.print').click(function(){
      var countItem = arr.length;
      $('.table').append('<thead><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Count</th>');
   $('.table').append('<tbody>');
   for (var i = 0; i < countItem; i++) {
   var id = arr[i].id;
   var name = arr[i].name
   var date = arr[i].date;
   var count = arr[i].count; 
   $('.table').append('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + count + '</td></tr>');
   }
   $('.table').append('</tbody>');
   $('#sort').show();
   $('.print').hide();
  });
    $('#table1, th').click(function() {
  //здесь нужно придумать код сортировки 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="openModule">Open Modal</button>
<div class="module">
   <div>
 <button class="closeModule">X</button>
 <h2>Модальное окно</h2>
 <button class="print">Print table</button>
 <select id="sort">
  <option>Без сортировки</option>
  <option>По убыванию</option>
  <option>По возрастанию</option>
 </select>
 <div class="item-table">
  <table class="table" id="table1"></table>
 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Вася',
    date: '15.06.2018',
    count: 11
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Петя',
    date: '23.1.2018',
    count: 23
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Иван',
    date: '12.03.2017',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Александр',
    date: '20.12.2010',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Евгений',
    date: '12.09.2018',
    count: 112
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Мария',
    date: '1.08.2016',
    count: 122
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Анастасия',
    date: '20.11.2018',
    count: 34
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Степан',
    date: '12.1.2019',
    count: 10
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.openModule').click(function() {
    $('.module').show();
    $('.openModule').hide();
  });
  $('.closeModule').click(function() {
    $('.module').hide();
    $('.openModule').show();
  });
  $('.print').click(function() {
    $('.table').append(`<thead>
        <th data-sortprop="id">ID</th>
        <th data-sortprop="name">Name</th>
        <th data-sortprop="date">Date</th>
        <th data-sortprop="count">Count</th>
      </thead>`).append('<tbody></tbody>');
    fillTable();
    $('#sort').show();
    $('.print').hide();
  });
  $('.table').on('click', 'th', function() {
    var prop = $(this).data("sortprop");
    var asc = $(this).data("sortdir") != "desc";
    //console.clear();
    //console.log(prop, asc);
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a[prop] == b[prop])
        return 0;
      var res = (a[prop] < b[prop])? -1 : 1;
      return asc? res : -res;
    });
    $(this).data("sortdir", asc? "desc" : "asc");
    fillTable();
  });

  $('.print').click();
});

function fillTable() {
  $('.table tbody').empty()
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var id = arr[i].id;
    var name = arr[i].name
    var date = arr[i].date;
    var count = arr[i].count;
    $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + count + '</td></tr>');
  }
}
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="openModule">Open Modal</button>
<div class="module">
  <div>
    <button class="closeModule">X</button>
    <h2>Модальное окно</h2>
    <button class="print">Print table</button>
    <select id="sort">
      <option>Без сортировки</option>
      <option>По убыванию</option>
      <option>По возрастанию</option>
    </select>
    <div class="item-table">
      <table class="table" id="table1" border="1"></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Только переведите числа в числа, а даты в даты - в объектах массива.

Comment: не уверен, что это работает

Comment: @ГеоргийВасильев если не уверены, то пишите почему, иначе подобное утверждение просто шум ;-)

Comment: @Kromster есть подозрение, что суть претензии в некорректной сортировке по дате. Думаю, что у ТС, именно это и вызвало проблему, но он об этом умолчал, решив, что телепатам нужно потренироваться ;-)

Comment: @UModeL, никого не хотел обидеть, работаю на умением выражать мысли)