# Сортировка таблицы по нажатию на заголовок столбца

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

как можно отсортировать столбец при нажатии на имя колонки? 
Я знаю, что данный вопрос поднимался уже, но там совсем другой код, в котором я не смог разобраться. Данные таблицы из БД. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
Я не знаю, как тут вставить PhP код, поэтому добавлю его в HTML.

```html
<?php
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_name = "test_codez";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";

$db = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die ("Невозможно подключиться к БД");

?>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table2";

      echo "<table>";
      echo "<table><tr><th>Alphabetic</th><th>Numeric</th><th>Date</th><th>Unsortable</th></tr>";
      $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM test_table2");
      while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
      {
      echo "<tr><td>".$result['Alphabetic']."</td><td>".$result['Numeriс']."</td><td>".$result['Date']."</td><td>".$result['Unsortable']."</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </table>
  </body>

  </html>
```

[image: таблица]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933370/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/933383?noredirect=1#comment1548465_933383

Comment: Это же js, не ? Да и там представлена таблица полная через html, нет вызова из бд. Прошу помочь по моему коду!

Comment: Как Вы думаете, в каком коде (PHP или JS) происходит "нажатие на заголовок столбца"?

Comment: @igor я признаю, ошибся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С начала было реализованно с помощью baseTable, после с помощью функции на js

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    (function(f) {
        function g(c) {
            return function(b, a) {
                b = b.cells[c].textContent;
                a = a.cells[c].textContent;
                b = +b || b;
                a = +a || a;
                return b > a ? 1 : b < a ? -1 : 0
            }
        }
        
        var d = document.querySelector(f),
            e = [].slice.call(d.rows, 1);
        [].slice.call(d.rows[0].cells).forEach(function(c, b) {
            var a = 0;
            c.addEventListener("click", function() {
                e.sort(g(b));
                a && e.reverse();
                e.forEach(function(a) {
                    d.appendChild(a)
                });
                a ^= 1
            })
        })
    })(".sort")
});
```